# value not being replaced in map containing function

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I am trying to get the value item.path replaced and outputted in console log - code works in chrome dev tools.

```js
const cars = [{name: "Saab", type: "car" }, {name: "Volvo", type: "car" }, {name: "BMW", type: "car"}];

const dataTest = cars.map(item => {
  const renderData = {}

  renderData[item.name] = {
    render: (value) => { 
        myFunction(value, item.type)
      },
  }
   
  console.log('Item', item.type); // This comes back with correct value car
  return renderData;
})

console.log('Data Test', dataTest);
```

List of array coming back from Data Test - console log from above, for some reason its not replacing the path, I have tried with braces (i.e. myFunction(value, `${item.path}`)) but that just changes the output below with braces, its not getting item.path from the array and replacing it, can't figure out why

Output from above code, you will see its item.type and not coming bar with car as the type:

```
Saab
: 
render
: 
value => { myFunction(value, item.type); }
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: It's not very clear what you expect to see. If you call the render function it'll pass "car" as the second parameter to `myFunction`.

Comment: the main reason wanting it to replaced, is i need to concat it with another object, that object has the type, and if i concat this it will not have replaced it with the type but have the value item.type.

Comment: That also makes very little sense. It would be better if you showed your *actual* use case and asked how to make it work. As such this is a prime example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are expecting `item.type` to be replaced in the output, but it's probably working the way you want it...

Ie if I add a simple `myFunction` with the correct signature, it will log out the correct value of `item.type` ...

```js
const cars = [
  {name: "Saab", type: "car1" }, 
  {name: "Volvo", type: "car2" }, 
  {name: "BMW", type: "car3"}
];

const dataTest = cars.map(item => {
  const renderData = {}

  renderData[item.name] = {
    render: (value) => { 
        myFunction(value, item.type)
      },
  }
  return renderData;
})

function myFunction(v, t) {
  console.log(`v: ${v}    t: ${t}`);
}

dataTest[0].Saab.render("foo");
dataTest[1].Volvo.render("bar");
dataTest[2].BMW.render("baz");
```

Comment: You right, it was me being a numpty, i though in the console log it would have replaced it with the type, but calling the function does exactly what it suppose to. Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Think i might have resolved it, required back ticks for the value

```
render: 
`(value) => { 
        myFunction(value, ${item.type})
 }`
```

Comment: This way you are making `render` a string instead of a function ...

Comment: you right just noticed it :(